# CA0001 : Member FirstOrDefault could not be found, code analysis error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-analysis, fxcop

On one of our solutions, with Code Analysis (CA) turned on, we get the error:

```
CA0001 : Member 'FirstOrDefault' could not be found in type 'System.Linq.Enumerable' in assembly '[our project]'.
```

Looking on the internet ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245246.aspx ), Microsoft tells us to look in the CodeAnalysisReport.xml file. But nowhere on my machine a file like that exists.

Also the msdn page tells us to look into custom rules, but we do not have any custom rules.

Can someone please get us into the right direction how to fix this? Or how to get some more information about this strange behavior of CA?

**Edit: @25 apr 2012 - 10:38**

After some investigation of the output of VS2010, i found a file [mydll].CodeAnalysisLog.xml in the bin/debug directory. There the error is more specified:

```
  <Exception Keyword="CA0001" Kind="AssemblyLoad">
   <Type>Microsoft.FxCop.Common.AssemblyLoadException</Type>
   <ExceptionMessage>Member 'FirstOrDefault' could not be found in type 'System.Linq.Enumerable' in assembly 'Prodigy.UI.Modules.SecurityDesigner.Silverlight, Version=0.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fdb1b3fc35f0c32e'.</ExceptionMessage>
   <StackTrace>   at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Phoenix.LoadAndResolutionHandler.HandleFailureToFindMatch(ModuleUnit unit, String memberName, Type memberType, String className, UInt32 memberRefToken, UInt32 classToken)
   at Phx.Metadata.ReaderImplementation.GetExternalDefinitionMemberSymbolHelper(UInt32 memberToken, String name, Byte* signature, Symbol parentSymbol, Symbol originalParentSymbol)
   at Phx.Metadata.ReaderImplementation.GetExternalDefinitionMemberSymbolHelper(UInt32 memberToken, String name, Byte* signature, Symbol parentSymbol, Symbol originalParentSymbol)
   at Phx.Metadata.LoaderImplementation.GetExternalDefinitionMemberSymbol(UInt32 memberToken)
   at Phx.Metadata.LoaderImplementation.GetMemberReferenceSymbol(UInt32 memberReferenceToken)
   at Phx.Metadata.MetadataLoader.LoadMemberReferences(AssemblyUnit unit)
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Phoenix.AssemblyLoader.LoadAssembly(String filePath)
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Phoenix.PhoenixAnalysisEngine.AnalyzeInternal()
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Phoenix.PhoenixAnalysisEngine.Analyze()
   at Microsoft.FxCop.Common.EngineManager.Analyze(Project project, Boolean verboseOutput)</StackTrace>
  </Exception>
```

But still the question remains, how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I recently stumbled onto this problem and after traditional headbashing, the solution was quite funny. The breaking change was referencing a custom portable library in my project. This effectively brought two sets of system references in the result. Meaning System.Core was referenced twice as 4.0.0.0 and 2.0.whatever. And looks like fxcop is not smart enough to handle that (the code was working, it's really validation only).

**tl;dr** Check what is effectively referenced by your troubled assembly. make sure no overlaps-replicants have made into your assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Check into your code, if the member 'FirstOrDefault' in type 'System.Linq.Enumerable' in assembly '[mydll].Silverlight, Version=0.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=fdb1b3fc35f0c32e'?

Through the error description, it seems that you have a "System.Linq.Enumerable" class in the [mydll].Silerlight.dll assembly, is this right?

Snippet from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstscode/thread/c2165692-67ea-4b4a-b730-52f4b4ff0313/